# symbolic definite integral using matlab

Tags: definite-integrals, matlab

I have this function 
$$
\frac{di}{dt} = - \frac{R}{L} i
$$

I know the solution which is 
$$
i(t) = i_{0} e^{- \frac{R}{L} (t-t_{0})}
$$
I would like to get the same solution by using Matlab. How can I do that?

Edit:

The solution is

```
>> syms L R i
>> dsolve('Di = -R/L*i', 'i(t0) = i0')
```

Comment: do you want to compute $i(t)$ vs. $t$?

Comment: It has been a while since I used Matlab, and i did not know that they did such symbolic computation? if this is true then awesome. But why matlab and not mathematica or maple?

Comment: After a quick search on a certian giant engine..I found [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/solve-a-single-differential-equation.html)

Comment: @Chinny84: To compute means to calculate in numerical way. He asked to compute, not to solve.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra, I'm sorry for the ambiguity. What I meant is how can I get the solution using Matlab. I have edited the post though.

Comment: @CroCo: thanks. Now it's clear what is your question.

Comment: @croco do you mean solve symbolical? Or solve numerically?

Comment: @Chinny84, symbolically.

Comment: I've tried this `>> syms x a b
>> int(1/x, a, b)` and I got `Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 
 
ans =
 
piecewise([a <= 0 and 0 <= b, int(1/x, x = a..b)], [0 < a or b < 0, log(b) - log(a)])`

Comment: I suppose that your equation should be $\frac{di}{i} = - \frac{R}{L} dt$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thanks for the correction. Actually it is $$
\frac{di}{dt} = - \frac{R}{L} i
$$ but they are same.

Comment: It is just funny that nobody noticed that ! More funny is that I am almost blind (this is not a joke) ! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following codes should work, [see](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html)

```
syms R L i(t) i0
dsolve(diff(i) == -R/L*i, i(0) == i0)
```

Comment: I got an error '??? Error using ==> syms at 61
Not a valid variable name.' It seems `i(t)` works with the new version of Matlab not the version I'm using. I came across this function `evalin()` but I don't know how can I use it.

Comment: @Omar, I solved the problem using `>> syms L R i
>> dsolve('Di = -R/L*i', 'i(0) = i0')`. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i would suggest this also, but you acted before me. Also you don't need to declare L, R, i symbolically in this method. Just dsolve('Di = -R/L*i', 'i(0) = i0') should work.

Comment: But I don't know how to specify the time's definite limits.

Comment: I have to declare `L, R, i` otherwise I got an error.

Comment: May be the error related with your software version.

Comment: Any idea about how to specify the time's limits?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by time's limit? You can integrate an expression from one symbolic variable to another one by `int` function. For example 

    syms x t1 t2
    int(f(x),t1,t2)
where `f` is a function of `x`

Comment: What I meant in the solution ($t-t_{0}$) but `dsolve()` assumes $t_{0} = 0$ but I solved the problem by doing `dsolve('Di = -R/L*i', 'i(t0) = i0')`. Now it is working.